# how to read a list from a file which has mixed types of data?

Tags: import, data

I need to read in a file with the first several lines reading as

```
SF,   2,   2,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     0.3141592653589793116),     0.0000000000000000000, -1000.0000000000000000000,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     0.0000000000000000000),   -1,
SF,   2,   0,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     0.3141592653589793116), -1000.0000000000000000000,  -333.3333333333333712289,     0.2746530255945797139+I(    -0.0001106096657636321),    1,
SF,   2,   2,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     0.3141592653589793116), -1000.0000000000000000000,  -333.3333333333333712289,     0.4718774055388476052+I(    -0.0003318288732658922),    1,
```

I need to read it into a list and then partition it into a matrix for subsequent treatment. My questions is how to read this mixed data set into a list? After it is read in, what type of data it is? It seems SF will not be stored as string, I need to use ToString to force it to be interpreted as string.

Comment: it seems there is no ready way to read in this mixed type data, is it? I used the following script to do it, can you take a look to see whether there are alternative simpler ways?

Comment: Have you tried `Import["D:\Code_Develop\data_mathematica.cvs", "Table"]`? Tweak options as seen fit.

Comment: Many thanks! It seems Import (with format "CSV") does the same thing as OpenRead+ReadList+StringSplit in what I posted below. To transfer them to be usable forms like into numbers, strings etc, are there more compact ways to use to replace the role of two For loops in my post?

Comment: Supposedly, anything that's a number in the file is supposed to come out as a number in *Mathematica*, and a string otherwise. Did you see any unexpected behavior? If you want to check the list produced, try applying `InputForm[]`.

Comment: I think it reads everything as strings. I checked with a presumably number multiplied with 2, and the output is not equal to a number multiplying 2. The default behavior might depend on what the type of the first entry Mathematica determines it to be, which I am not sure.

Comment: @Guess who it is: what did you actually edit my original post? I guess I had done it right this time ...

Comment: I just [added a tag](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/83684/revisions). Can you try posting a smaller dummy version of your file that can be used for testing?

Comment: should I simply shorten the input lines? I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no ready way to read in this mixed type data. I used the following script to do it, can you take a look to help improve it? The code itself has been tested working, but not quite in the flow of mathematica.

```
 f = OpenRead["D:\Code_Develop\data_mathematica.cvs"];
 cc = ReadList[f, String];
 data1 = StringSplit[cc, ","]; ccm = data1;
 nn = Dimensions[ccm]; nn1 = nn[[1]];
 For[i = 1, i ≤ nn1, i++,
     ccm[[i, 1]] = StringTake[data1[[i, 1]], -2];
     For[j = 2, j ≤ 8, j++,
       ccm[[i, j]] = ToExpression[data1[[i, j]]];
       ]
     ];
 Close[f];
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @guess I would use `Import[..., "Table"]` to read in the data as a mixture of strings and numeric values, then use a rule to convert the complex values (with not a `For` loop in sight!).  This method does not require you to know the complex column positions in advance.

Firstly I copied and pasted your example data to create a string:

```
stringData = 
  "SF,   2,   2,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     \
0.3141592653589793116),     0.0000000000000000000, \
-1000.0000000000000000000,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     \
0.0000000000000000000),   -1,
SF,   2,   0,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     \
0.3141592653589793116), -1000.0000000000000000000,  \
-333.3333333333333712289,     0.2746530255945797139+I(    \
-0.0001106096657636321),    1,
SF,   2,   2,     0.0000000000000000000+I(     \
0.3141592653589793116), -1000.0000000000000000000,  \
-333.3333333333333712289,     0.4718774055388476052+I(    \
-0.0003318288732658922),    1,";
```

Then I have to use the equivalent of `Import` for strings, [`ImportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html).

```
ImportString[stringData, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ","] /. 
 s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "+I("] :> ToExpression[s]
```

> {{"SF", 2, 2, 0.*10^-19 + 0.314159265358979312 I, 
>     0., -1000.000000000000000000, 0.*10^-19 + 0.*10^-19 I, -1}, {"SF",    2, 0, 0.*10^-19 + 
>      0.314159265358979312 I, -1000.000000000000000000,
>   -333.333333333333371229, 0.274653 - 0.00011061 I, 1}, {"SF", 2, 2, 
>     0.*10^-19 + 
>      0.314159265358979312 I, -1000.000000000000000000, 
>   -333.333333333333371229, 0.471877 - 0.000331829 I, 1}}

Obviously, to read from a file use `Import["D:\\Code_Develop\\data_mathematica.cvs", ...` instead and if you are using a version of *Mathematica* prior to 10.1 use `StringMatchQ[s, __ ~~ "+I(" ~~ __]` instead of `StringContainsQ[...]`.