# how to import plain text file, with mixed formats with strings that contain commas

Tags: import

I have been struggling with this basic task, and I am surprised it is this hard to do in *Mathematica*. I get lost in the maze of Import and options and sub-options and after trying many things, still not able to figure how to do it.

There are few questions on this, but none of them have the answer that works for me. Here is the problem. I have plain text file. Each line has this mixed format

```
  number,number,string,number,number,string,string
```

The strings are quoted, and a string can also have commas and escaped "\" characters in it. So reading the line as string and using `StringSplit` on comma and such, does not really work.

Here is example of the file. 2 lines only: (call it test.txt)

```
9,1,"",19,0.0151,"This , is string one"," this is \\ another string"
10,2,"note",22,0.0199,"This , also string"," and this too"
```

I need to read this file into *Mathematica*, so I can process each line.

Clearly, the result of the import should be a list of lists. Each one of
the lists represent one line. This is what I tried

1) Using `Import` with `Table`

```
data = Import["test.txt", "Table"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem with this, is that each line in one full string!

```
data[[1]] // FullForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So one has to parse out the entries out, which does not work, since strings can has commas in them also. So can't use `StringSplit` and use "," as separator.

2) Looked at supported elements in file

```
 data = Import["test.txt", "Elements"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Plaintext` does not work. It reads the whole file as one string. Same as using `String`. Also `Lines` does not work. Same problem. Same as `Data`.

3) tried to use CVS. renamed the file to CVS, but *Mathematica* did not like it.

```
 data = Import["test.cvs", "CVS"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

3) tried "TSV"

```
data = Import["test.txt", "TSV"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but again, each list is actually one string. Back to square one.

related questions

[how-to-read-a-list-from-a-file-which-has-mixed-types-of-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83684/how-to-read-a-list-from-a-file-which-has-mixed-types-of-data) with answer there that says `It seems there is no ready way to read in this mixed type data.` The answer there does not work, since it uses `StringSplit` on commas, which does not work in this case.

And others, but none of them really have a solution to this basic issue.

In Matlab, this is trivial to do. Matlab has [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) which I use for everything.

```
fileID = fopen('test.txt','r');
data = textscan(fileID,'%d %d %q %d %f %q %q','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
```

Anyone knows how to do the same in *Mathematica*? Using 10.3.1 on windows 7.

Comment: Importing as CSV worked for me with V10.3.0 running on OS X 10.10.2. I put the two lines you gave as an example in a file called `test.csv` on my desktop and imported it into a _Mathematica_ notebook. I got the following (FullForm): `List[List[9, 1, "", 19, 0.0151, "This , is string one", 
  " this is \\\\ another string"], List[10, 2, "note", 22, 0.0199, "This , also string", " and this too"]]`. Why is this not a good result?

Comment: @m_goldberg as I mentioned in the post, I get an error when using CVS. I also renamed the file as cvs and tried it. I mentioned this in the question, I am on windows 7, 10.3.1. Please see 3) above. It could be a different OS thing issue.

Comment: I read the post carefully, and I'm aware of what you said. But I can not replicate your error on my system. Are you saying that code like `Import[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.csv"}]]` doesn't work on your system because you are on Windows or because you are using V10.3.1 rather than V10.3.0?

Comment: @m_goldberg if I just use `Import["test.csv"]` I do not get an error, but the data read is one long string. Which is not what I want. If I use `Import["test.csv","CVS"]` I get an error. I do not know why you did not get one long string on your end. Here is screen shot:  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FwWkd.png)

Comment: Note I did not give the 2nd element "CVS" -- which is not a mime type -- perhaps you meant "CSV", but you should not have to specify that.

Comment: @m_goldberg  OMG! You are right. I used the wrong 3 letters. When I changed the file name to `test.csv` from `test.cvs` then it worked :)  Sorry about the confusion. You method also works. I have a pharmacy called CVS next to where I live, may be that is why I made this mistake.

Comment: I make the same mistake time to time when giving an extension to my filenames. Don't feel too bad. I have to say out loud, Comma Separated Variables as I type the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `"FieldSeparators"` for `"Table"` do not match the field separators in your file.  Set them to your required separators. Look at the *Import options* subsection of the **Options** section in [`"Table"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) documentation.

```
data = Import["test.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {","}]
```

> {{9, 1, 19, 0.0151, "This , is string one", 
>     " this is \\ another string"}, {10, 2, "note", 22, 0.0199, 
>     "This , also string", " and this too"}}

Hope this helps.

Comment: great! this option did it. I am surprised no one mentioned this option in all the questions I looked at.